# Eshell/Shell aliases to M-x

Tags: emacs, elisp, eshell

In Emacs, How I can invoke the alias with M-x ?  For example, I have alias to open the file as in 'alias ff find-file $1'.  I like to invoke it as M-x ff RETURN $1.  Similarly, I have defined alias for viewing directories, and I like to invoke that with M-x without providing arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that you should define your alias as being a global Emacs alias rather than one specific to Eshell:

```
(defalias 'ff 'find-file)
```

Comment: Excellent. This works as expected.  Is there a way for automatic conversion using something like eshell-alias-load-hook?